# My templated helper using a DropDownListFor does NOT reflect the model of enum. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model as follows:

```
namespace Q01.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Sex? Sex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A utilities class to obtain a `SelectList` object to populate a `DropDownListFor` is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Q01.Utilities
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static SelectList EnumToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum? obj) where TEnum: struct
        {
            var values = from TEnum x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                         select new { Value = x, Text = x };
            return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
}
```

I create a templated helper named `Sex.cshtml` for the type of `Sex` as follows:

```
@using Q01.Utilities
@using Q01.Models
@model Sex?
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, Model.EnumToSelectList(), "--Select--")
```

In `HomeController`, I create an instance of `Person` and pass it to the view as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Q01.Models;

namespace Q01.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Sex = Sex.Female;
            return View(p);
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding view is declared as follows:

```
@using Q01.Utilities
@model Q01.Models.Person
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Using Sex.cshtml: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sex)</div>
    <div>Not using Sex.cshtml: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Sex, Model.Sex.EnumToSelectList(), "--Select--")</div>
}
```

The screenshot of the output is shown as follows:

[image]

The question is: why the `Sex.cshtml` does not reflect the model? It should select `Female` rather than "--Select--".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add value to `EnumToSelectList`:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static SelectList EnumToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum? obj, object value) where TEnum: struct
    {
        var values = from TEnum x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                     select new { Value = x, Text = x };
        return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", value);
    }
}
```

Then `Model.EnumToSelectList(x.Sex)`. You just have to provide selected value in `SelectList` constructor.

Comment: I think we don't need to create a new parameter. We can replace 'value' with `obj` and it still works. Right?

Comment: @user596314: Yes, you are right. It is 5am, I should go to sleep.